# How to merge an already existing Entity into persistance context

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, persistence

I have following Entitys:

A Task and an Tag, Both have an Many to Many relationship on DB side, but in my Application I dont really need the Information, so I didnt use the @ManyToMany Annotation.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
@Table(name = "TASK")
@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Task {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "text")
    private String text;

    @Column(name = "creation_time", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @CreatedDate
    private Instant creationTime;

    @Column(name = "update_time", nullable = false)
    @LastModifiedDate // die By Variante ist dann interessant für Spring Security
    private Instant updateTime;

    @Column(name = "completion_time")
    private Instant completionTime;

    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @JoinTable(
            name = "join_table",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "task_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id"))
    private Set<Tag> tags;

    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    @Transient
    private Boolean checked;

    @PostLoad
    @PostPersist
    @PostRemove
    @PostUpdate
    private void afterAnyUpdate() {
        checked = completionTime != null;
    }
}
```

Tag:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
@Table(name = "TAG")
@Entity
public class Tag {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String text;
}
```

However, when I try to Persist a Task with an already existing Tag I get the Error: detached entity passed to persist. (This is a usecase that CAN happen in my Application)

```
POST http://localhost:8080/tasks
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "text": "neueTask",
  "checked": false,
  "tags": [
    {
      "id": 3,
      "text": "ersterTag"
    },
    {
      "text": "dritter"
    }
  ]
}
```

So Far so Good, thats the behavior I already expected, because the Tag got detached from the persistance Context.

BUT

when I Try to merge the detached Tag into my persistance context, nothing changes.

I still get the same error, that tells me that im trying so persist an detached entity.

(this is my Task Service, where the Processing of the HTTP Request is handled)

```
@PersistenceContext 
private EntityManager manager;

public Task saveNewTask(Task taskToSave) {
    taskToSave.getTags().forEach(tag -> {
        if(this.manager.contains(tag)) {
            manager.merge(tag);
        }
    });
    return repository.save(taskToSave);
}
```

Why is that ?

(This is my first question on stackoverflow, so if u need additional Information - let me know!)

Comment: When you do a `merge` you have to retrieve the return value : the return value of the `merge` mtehod is the merged entity. Therefore, if you want to make the `merge` effective you have to use the returned value.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to understand the entity lifecycle. Detached means that the entity has an id, but is not known to the current persistence context. You have 3 ways to transition an object to the managed state from the detached state.

- `EntityManager#find()` to load the object from the DB
- `EntityManager#getReference()` to get a proxy for the object (when you assume it exists on the DB)
- `EntityManager#merge()` to load the object from the DB and flush changes at the same time

Since you seem to want to flush changes, using `merge` is fine, but the code you wrote doesn't really make sense, because with `contains` you are essentially asking if the persistence context contains the object, which is not what you need.

You should rather check if the object has an identifier assigned:

```java
@Transactional
public Task saveNewTask(Task taskToSave) {
    taskToSave.getTags().forEach(tag -> {
        if(this.manager.getEntityManagerFactory().getPersistenceUnitUtil().getIdentifier(tag) != null) {
            manager.merge(tag);
        }
    });
    return repository.save(taskToSave);
}
```